# What is most likely cause for unstable system

Tags: cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting

I had a stable system, Intel based i7, Asus ROG RAMPAGE V EDITION 10, then upgraded to a ROG ZENITH II EXTREME motherboard with new Threadripper CPU, 3960X. All other parts were from original system, new CPU and Motherboard, and an AOI cooler to suit were only new parts.

System became unstable, Freezing randomly, and power cycling randomly. Five times per day, at least. I replace CPU and system was stable for 20 days and then started being unstable again.

I got motherboard replaced, but that model was no longer available. So I ordered new ROG ZENITH II EXTREME ALPHA motherboard. This seemed to have fixed the issue, it was freezing and power cycling every day and that pretty much went away. I thought I had resolved the issue.

Now I have had system running for three months and I have had one Freeze, and two power cycles. So I am at a loss at what could be the problem. Replacing CPU + Mobo has stopped it crashing 5 times a day so it is much more stable, but what is most likely to cause this? Also, why infrequent hangs and crashes now. Perhaps my power supply or my RAM?

Also, my local computer shop reproduced the issue with just the CPU and motherboard, but it was stable for two days until we tested it with the Asus m.2 hyper x16 SSD raid card. Could it be an issue with the Raid card? I have tried two Gigabyte raid cards, and then switched to Asus model, so I have tried different brands as well as models. Perhaps a bandwidth issue that is only happening with Raided NVMe drives?

**Summary**

New parts: Motherboard, CPU and AIO Cooler.

System became unstable.

Replaced: CPU then Motherboard.

System became much more stable but still occasionally freezes and power cycles.

I'm at a loss at what to try replacing next. I hope someone can suggest the most likely cause otherwise I may have to build a whole new machine from scratch and that is not currently in my budget.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of system reboots or hangs is incompatible devices & device drivers.

Suggest you follow the following steps to isolate the issue:

1. Make sure you have installed the latest UEFI for the motherboard and any other firmware updates for your components, graphics card, etc. Reset your motherboard to factory defaults.
2. To isolate if the problem is caused by hardware or software, boot to a Linux Live CD.  For example, boot a USB key with Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon. https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php   If you're able to recreate the hang running on the Linux Live CD it tells you the problem is hardware-related, and not your operating system or operating system drivers.
3. If it's hardware related, take your system to a bare minimum and gradually add components back in.  For example if you have 4 memory dimms, run with only 1 or 2 dimms.  Through swapping see if you can isolate it to a bad component. Definitely reseat the dimms and making sure the gold connections are clean.

4. You don't mention what operating system you're running, but check the system logs for any information on errors.  Windows System and Application logs.

Comment: No wrong answers here. Windows 10. Emailed ASUS and they sent me a link to a support page that had drivers and a new BIOS that were not listed in the app that checks for new bios versions (Armoury). I installed the new drivers and 
installed the new BIOS and have had no crashes or hangs since. I am holding my breath but it has been two weeks with no issues. Touch wood. It's entirely possible it was a BIOS issue that has been fixed. Only time will tell.

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU freezes, typically the screen will freeze (in my experience. But sure not always)

If the Ram is corrupt - typically it will either reboot or do a bsod dump. (again in my experience, and again... not always)

If the GPU is bad there usually is a corrupt image, and the Display server reboots. Also it can just BSOD and reboot...

The only way to find out is to swap out parts, in this case ram.

What its probably not...

Probably not the PSU - Usually those just overheat and die, but it COULD be undervolting - Which MIGHT happen during games (and probably only)

ITs probably not the disk drives. youd get an obvious BSOD (some IO error...)

It COULD be some screwy USB peripheral - that has happened to be once before, but thats rare.

Always... troubleshooting really is the only way to find out.

You replaced the board and processor... GPU and RAM are left. (reasonably)